# Вывести из базы данных подкатегории определенной категории

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

В базе есть таблица `directions` - в ней содержатся категории, например: авто, аниме, города. Структура таблицы: id - AUTO_INCREMENT, name - название категории(авто например).

Есть еще таблица `poDdirections` - в ней содержатся подкатегории какой либо категории. Структура таблицы:  id - AUTO_INCREMENT, iDdirections - в ней содержится *id*, который указывает к какой из категорий пренадлежит эта подкатегори, name - название подкатегории(Mustang например).

В базе есть записи:

**directions**:

```
id = 1; name = Авто;
```

**poDdirections**:

```
id = 1; iDdirections  = 1; name = Mustang; 
id = 2; iDdirections  = 1; name = Ford;
id = 3; iDdirections  = 1; name = Ford;
```

Мне нужно вывести категории(directions) и под ними подкатегории(poDdirections), принадлежащие выводимой категории.

Делаю так:

```
$napr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `directions` ORDER BY `id` DESC"); //Выводим категории

while ($dID = mysql_fetch_assoc($napr))

{


echo '<a href="/" title="'.htmlspecialchars($dID['name']).'" >'.htmlspecialchars($dID['name']).'</a>'; 



$naprPod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poDdirections` WHERE `iDdirections` = '$dID[id]' ORDER BY `id` DESC"); //Выводим подкатегории выведенной категории

while ($dIDpoD = mysql_fetch_assoc($naprPod))

{

echo '<a href="/" title="'.htmlspecialchars($dIDpoD['name']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($dIDpoD['name']).'</a>';

}



}
```

В результате получается что в категории выводит только одну последнюю подкатегорию.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Меня смущает $dID[id] в запросе. Возможно, необходимо использовать $dID["id"]?

Comment: @ЭдуардЗабоев это не меняет результат вывода подкатегорий

Comment: А можете привести полный код страницы?

Comment: @ЭдуардЗабоев ну так я же предоставил полный код запроса. зачем вам код страницы? там просто разметка

Comment: Я проверил ваш код у себя. Он полностью рабочий. Выводятся все категории (и с кавычками в ключе и без кавычек). Возможно - проблема в базе данных?

Comment: @ЭдуардЗабоев Большое вам спасибо. оказалось дело в разметке страницы было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы не городить огороды и фигачить запросы в циклах (о ужас) и воспользоваться такой функцией в `MYSQL` как `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT d.id AS `direstion_id`, d.`name`, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`name` ORDER BY `name` DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
    FROM `poDdirections` 
    WHERE iDdirections = d.`id`
) AS `sub_category_names` 
FROM `directions` d
LEFT JOIN poDdirections pd
ON d.`id` = pd.`iDdirections`
GROUP BY d.`id`
```

в результате получим поля:

- direction_id - соответствует `id` категории
- name - соответствует `name` категории
- sub_category_names - в нем лежат имена через запятую всех подкатегорий, которые входят в данную категорию.

Эти имена потом можно разделить через `php` функцию под названием `explode`

В итоге ваш цикл будет примерно таким:

```
while ($direction = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<a href="/" title="'.htmlspecialchars($direction['name']).'" >'.htmlspecialchars($direction['name']).'</a>'; 
    $subcategory = explode(',', $direction['sub_category_names']);
    foreach ($subcategory as $sub) {
        echo '<a href="/" title="'.htmlspecialchars($sub).'">'.htmlspecialchars($sub).'</a>';
    }
}
```

Проверить мне не на чем. Но вроде не ошибся

Comment: не могли бы вы этот код встроить в мой как-нибудь. я не совсем его понимаю(

Comment: Обновил. Но лучше вам самостоятельно сделать запрос к бд, в какой-либо визуальной среде, посмотреть результат и на основе него сделать логику вывода данных